# Get notification from WKWebView to Swift when specific screen is shown in html

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a [sample](https://previews.envatousercontent.com/files/240466341/index.html) html

I am using `WKWebView` to show this html. What I want is that when user finishes the game, i.e when "high score" screen appears, we get notification inside our code as well (i.e swift), so that we dismiss the view on that and get the highest score.

What is the possible way to do so?

I have done the following but  its not giving any function

```
func showHtml5()
{
    var wkWebView = WKWebView()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    contentController.add(self, name: "onVisibilityChanged")

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController

    wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: config)
    wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self as? WKNavigationDelegate


    if let url = URL(string: "https://previews.envatousercontent.com/files/240466341/index.html") {
        wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    self.destination.view.addSubview(wkWebView)

}

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print("message is :\(message)")

    if(message.name == " onVisibilityChanged") {
        print("FROM JAVASCRIPT")
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice [game](https://previews.envatousercontent.com/files/240466341/index.html) though...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't setup your communication completely. The swift setup looks fine, but your listener function isn't called, because you're not sending any messages. In order to receive a message from the web view, you need to post a message to that specific message handler. So if you register a message handler called `onVisibilityChanged`, you need to post a message to that handler from your javascript.

Inside you javascript eventListener do this:

```
function onVisibilityChanged() {
    if (document.hidden || document.mozHidden || document.webkitHidden || document.msHidden) {
        cr_setSuspended(true);
    } else {
        cr_setSuspended(false);
    }

    var message = {
        "whatever": "you want to send"
    }

    window.webkit.messageHandlers.onVisibilityChanged.postMessage(message);
};
```

Then read your message like this:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    guard let body = message.body as? [String:Any] else {
        return
    }

    print("message from the other side >> \(body["whatever"])")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `window.location = "<your protocol name>:<some payload>";`

It will fire the
`- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler` delegate method where you can check your protocol name with Cancel handling to prevent loading the page:

```
if ([navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding hasPrefix:@"<your protocol name>"]) {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
}
```

This example is for Objective-C from my project. Swift's implementation has a similar behavior.